# Having trouble installing VLC-2.0.3-5 on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player, aptitude

I know that the package is in the repository squeeze-backports, so I added that to my sources.list file.

One apt-get update later, I attempt to use

> sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install vlc

To no avail. It tells me that I don't have fonts-freefont-ttf, and that it's unavailable.
A quick search reveals that it's in the sid repository for debian. Added the sid, another update (which recommended that I install hundreds of upgrades), installed the font. Commented out the sid repository because I didn't want to be bothered by messages for upgrades.

Tried again. This time, the vlc-data failed. Went into aptitude and found that the vlc version listed was the old squeeze one. Went into aptitude -t squeeze-backports. Found the vlc that I was looking for and tried +-ing it in. Turns out that vlc-data is the problem, as it's the original squeeze one and not the newer backports version. Aptitude says that it's UNAVAILABLE for installation as well.
Found that the required newer version exists, but for some reason it's not listed in aptitude.

So I manually go to backports and dpkg -i the package to install it. Enter aptitude again and try to install vlc. Now libvlccore is the problem. Aparently it still doesn't recognize vlc-data-2.0.3-1. After a bit of looking, it seems like neither do any of the other packages.

And at this point, I'm stuck. I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tried using synaptic and attempt to fix the issue?

Comment: @Znau synaptic is just a gui front-end to apt, it doesn't do anything better than cli tools

Comment: @maxxvw that being true or not, i have successfully solved issues using synaptic i didn't manage to solve using cli.

Comment: Nice to see you finding a solution, that's not a clean one but why not...

Answer (score 0):

Debian has a multimedia "branch": [link](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/)

1. `echo "deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org squeeze main non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb-multimedia.list`
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get install vlc`